# Drop down list change function not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have two dropdowns, the second dropdown shall change when something is changed in the first dropdown, this is working fine in Firefox, but not in IE. (IE9). Then in the second dropdown, I'm looping through the items, and hiding some of them.

```
var intermin = '${intermin}'; 
var intermin2=intermin.substring(1,3);

$('#startSemester').change(function() {

    var start=$('#startSemester').val();
    var end=$('#endSemester').val();
    var start1=start.substring(0,1);
    var start2=start.substring(1,3);
    var start3="";
    var end3="";
    if (start1=="H"){
        start3="2";
    }
    else
        start3="1";
    var start4=start2+start3;

    $('#endSemester option').removeAttr("disabled");
    var endSemesters= $('#endSemester');

        $.each($('option', endSemesters), function(index, value) { 
            var end= ($(this).val());
            var end2=end.substring(1,3);
            var end1=end.substring(0,1);
            if (end1=="H"){
                end3="2";
            }
            else
                end3="1";
            var end4=end2+end3;
            $('#endSemester ' + 'option' + '[value =' + end + ']').show();  
            if (end4 < start4 || end2 > intermin2) {
                $('#endSemester ' + 'option' + '[value =' + end + ']').hide();
            }
        });
});
```

Is there some way of having this working in IE.

Comment: Not sure but var `end` might be a preserved word.
Can you change it and try again?

Comment: @TimVermaelen negative: [list of reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)

Comment: No, I changed to endsem and it didn't help.

Comment: ye checked it myself but it's stackoverflow coloring `end` then ^^

Comment: Does the event fire in IE? Have you tried to debug it and see if it fires at least?

Comment: I also see a misplaced space character at `[value =`. Other than that, provide an example with jsfiddle or something similar please.

Comment: Ah another thing:
`if (end4 < start4 || end2 > intermin2){/**/}` you should use `parseInt(val, raddix)` on those values because now it looks like you're doing `if ("apple" < "banana"){}` http://jsfiddle.net/tive/wU6XL/

Comment: Now, if I debug, it's going into the code, but it does'nt hide anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with IE is the hiding option part. IE doesn't support much CSS on option elements.
Especially `display: none` which is what `.hide()` does.

Therefor I believe it's best for you to disable the option.

```
var changeOption = $('#endSemester ' + 'option' + '[value=' + end + ']');

changeOption.prop("disabled", false);
if (parseInt(end4) < parseInt(start4) || parseInt(end2) > parseInt(intermin2)) {
    changeOption.prop("disabled", true);
}
```

You can test this in various browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/tive/wU6XL/

Or if you're persistent enough find a plugin that:

- hides the `select` control and uses a replacement `ul li` structure
- wraps `<option />` with a span ([demo1](http://fiddle.jshell.net/FAkEK/100/) [demo2](http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/demos/selectmenu/default.html))

PS: you might want to change the option values accordingly since I have no view on your HTML.

Comment: What about removing the option from the select's DOM, and adding it to an array somewhere in the event that it needs to be added back later.

Comment: I believe one of these demos works like that. Bottom line is you need an alternative in order to hide option elements x-browser.

Comment: It works, the options are greyed out, but it's not as beautiful as hide.

Answer (score -2):

Hey Please refer This code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWeeklyWeightIn" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Predictable">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Js Code Is

```
$('#ddlWeeklyWeightIn').on("change", function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
```

Please refer Link [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/SRq9g/)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: How exactly is this supposed to help?

Comment: You can't target ASP.NET controls like that, the ID is rendered differently on the page.

Comment: I agree But if you are giving ClientIDMode="Predictable" then no harm of that code. I have Just try to help you that's why i have created demo for you where I have taken only Select html control.Hope you undersatnd